# How to fit text (Arabic & English) in latex table

Tags: tables

lam trying to create the following table, l write this code but it doesn't produce the required table, the problem is at Arabic texts, English texts is wrapped.

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{Comparisons of different PVT systems, presented in 2014.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{6cm}|m{6cm}|}
 \hline 
 \textbf{ } & \textbf{arabic} &\textbf{english} \\
 \hline

\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Functional}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على التحقق من رقم هاتفه قبل عملية التسجيل الفعلية.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to verify his/her phone number before actual registration process.} \\\cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على حذف حسابه من نظام التطبيق.>} &   \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to delete his account from system of application.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على حذف صديق من أصدقائه.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{User shall be able to delete friend in his friends.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على رؤية موقع الأصدقاء على الخريطة الرئيسية.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to see location of friends on main map.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على تحديد المسافة كقطر لرؤية صديق في منطقة معينة.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to select the distance as diameter in order to see friend in certain area.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على الدردشة مع صديق واحد بينما يرى المستخدم موقعه و موقع صديقه.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to chat with one friend while user is seeing his location and his friend’s location.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<أثناء قيام المستخدم بإنشاء حدث خاص ، يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على اختيار الأصدقاء لمشاركة الحدث معهم فقط.>} & \multicolumn{1}{6ئm{6cm}|}{While user is creating private event, user shall be able to select friends in order to share event only with them.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على رؤية الأحداث الخاصة التي تمت مشاركتها معه على الخريطة.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to see private events that shared with him on map.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على رؤية جميع الأحداث المميزة على الخريطة.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to see all privileged events on map.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\<يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على إرسال طلب إلى مبتكر الحدث العام للانضمام إلى الحدث.>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to send a request to creator of public event for joining event.} \\\hline   

\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Non\_Functional}} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}\thead{\<نصصصص>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{textttttttttttttttttttttttttt} \\\cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} &   \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\<>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\hline  

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

This is the Required table:
[image: required table]

This is the code output:
[image: code output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with `\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}` instead of using `\<...>`:

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{Comparisons of different PVT systems, presented in 2014.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{6cm}|m{6cm}|}
 \hline 
 \textbf{ } & \textbf{arabic} &\textbf{english} \\
 \hline

\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Functional}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على التحقق من رقم هاتفه قبل عملية التسجيل الفعلية.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to verify his/her phone number before actual registration process.} \\\cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على حذف حسابه من نظام التطبيق.\end{arabtext}} &   \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to delete his account from system of application.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على حذف صديق من أصدقائه.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to delete friend in his friends.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على رؤية موقع الأصدقاء على الخريطة الرئيسية.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to see location of friends on main map.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على تحديد المسافة كقطر لرؤية صديق في منطقة معينة.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to select the distance as diameter in order to see friend in certain area.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على الدردشة مع صديق واحد بينما يرى المستخدم موقعه و موقع صديقه.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to chat with one friend while user is seeing his location and his friend’s location.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}أثناء قيام المستخدم بإنشاء حدث خاص ، يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على اختيار الأصدقاء لمشاركة الحدث معهم فقط.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{While user is creating private event, user shall be able to select friends in order to share event only with them.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على رؤية الأحداث الخاصة التي تمت مشاركتها معه على الخريطة.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to see private events that shared with him on map.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على رؤية جميع الأحداث المميزة على الخريطة.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to see all privileged events on map.} \\\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}يجب أن يكون المستخدم قادرًا على إرسال طلب إلى مبتكر الحدث العام للانضمام إلى الحدث.\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{6cm}|}{User shall be able to send a request to creator of public event for joining event.} \\\hline   

\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Non\_Functional}} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}نصصصص\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{textttttttttttttttttttttttttt} \\\cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} &   \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\begin{arabtext}...\end{arabtext}} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{} \\\hline  

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The output will be:[image]

I haven't included the whole table because in my example the table didn't fit in a single page

Comment: Thank you! it's worked.